# Print unique words, total number of occurrences and sum using `awk`

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

How can I print unique words, number of their occurrences and the sum of their values in the relevant column using a single array in `awk`?

I'm using `awk` like:

```
awk -F, '{sum[$1]+=$2} END{for (x in sum) print x, sum[x]}' inFile
```

Can I modify the command above to print the total number of occurrences of unique words as well? Something like the below result for the following sample input:

Result (the order of the printed results doesn't matter):

```
A 2 25 
B 1 12 
C 3 18
```

Input:

```
A,15
C,13
C,4
A,10
B,12
C,1
```

I can add another array to count them separately but I think there should be another way to print it just using the same array.

Is there any index of the array `sum` which stores the total words seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F, '{x[$1]["count"]++;x[$1]["sum"]+=$2}END{for(y in x){print y,x[y]["count"],x[y]["sum"]}}' in
```

Basically you replace the array with a multidimensional array in order to store both the count of the occurences of each unique first field and the sum of their relative second fields.

```
% cat in
A,15
C,13
C,4
A,10
B,12
C,1
% awk -F, '{x[$1]["count"]++;x[$1]["sum"]+=$2}END{for(y in x){print y,x[y]["count"],x[y]["sum"]}}' in
A 2 25
B 1 12
C 3 18
```

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no such index. Array values don't keep count of how many times they have been incremented. The most natural thing to do here is to use a second array:

```
$ awk -F, '{sum[$1]+=$2;seen[$1]++} END{for(x in sum) print x,seen[x],sum[x]}' file
A 2 25
B 1 12
C 3 18
```

You can also use a two dimensional array as shown in Kos's answer but, as you can see, that really doesn't simplify things in any way. Alternatively, you could use some perl magic:

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},${$k{$F[0]}}[-1]+$F[1]; 
            END{print "$_ ",$#{$k{$_}}+1," ${$k{$_}}[-1]" for keys(%k)}' file
C 3 18
B 1 12
A 2 25
```

No, that is not line noise and yes, it uses a single array to print everything.